# Override paintBorder() method again on mouseEntered() method

Tags: java, swing, border, jtextfield, look-and-feel

I'm in a part learning Look and Feels in java, so what I want is to override `paintBorder()` of a `JTextField` **again**. When I say again, it means that I have my own Look and Feel for `JTextField` which has curved corners (by overriding the `paintBorder()`) then I have a `MouseAdapter` namely Hover class to hover certain components in one class.

Now how can I override `paintBorder()` in my Hover class?

This is my `JTextField`

[image: JTextField using custom Look and Feel]

I tried using `setBorder()` in Hover class but it creates border on it's original component like this.

[image: Applying setBorder() effect on Hover]

So can anyone educate me on how to override the `paintBorder()` method again on Hover class? or better solution to change the custom border color?

extra codes:

```
//How I created the border at my own Look and Feel
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
g2.setColor(Color.black);
g2.drawRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth()-1, getHeight()-1, horizontalDiameter, verticalDiameter);//hDiameter and vDiamater are both 15
super.paintBorder(g);
```

in my Hover class:

```
if(e.getComponent() instanceof JTextField)
{
   JTextField textField = (JTextField) e.getComponent();
   textField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));//The wrong code
   //???
}
```

Comment: It appears you're in the process of making an unusable GUI (seriously, a round bordered text field which changes on mouse but not focus?), so beyond adding the Swing tag to get it in front of the Swing experts .. good luck! 

Comment: @AndrewThompson yes I'm exploring and understanding by experimenting and understanding in-field. Can u help instead? and give some thoughts? will it work?

Comment: *"give some thoughts?"* I already gave them, but to repeat *"It appears you're in the process of making an unusable GUI"*. In case it wasn't clear, I'm not going to help you do that. There are already too many demands on my time helping people who want to create *usable* GUIs to be bothered with this.